# Syntax error update case mysql

Tags: mysql, database, syntax-error

I am trying to update a table in my database, I have looked around but I cannot seem to get this to work.

What I am trying to achieve is to update the "quantity" column in my table.

If the quantity is > 0 then quantity - xxx value
if quantity is < 0 then set the status column to 0

Here is my code:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `update_quantity`(IN iarticleid varchar(45), IN iquantity int(11))
BEGIN
UPDATE product_varities set product_varities.quantity = CASE
WHEN product_varities.quantity > 0 Then product_varities.quantity = product_varities.quantity - iquantity
WHEN product_varities.quantity < 0 THEN product_varities.`status` = 0
WHERE product_varities.article_id = iarticleid;
END CASE;
END
```

Current error message shown in MySQL Workbench:
line 5- syntax error missing 'end'
line 7- syntax error missing 'end'

I have placed the "end" as you can see, I'm not sure what I am doing wrong. Can someone point me in the right direction. Thanks.

Comment: Been a while since i used a case in mysql... but could it be the semicolon at the end of the `WHERE` clause? Have you tried omitting it?

Comment: Put and END after 0 drop END CASE;

Comment: @Mihai I don't think that's the solution, because he wants to update more than one field. The updates must be separated in two to do what he wants.

Comment: i have tried removing the ; from where clause but it didnt help

Comment: @Harry Read carefully your query: You're trying to assign a value to the `quantity` column, but you are assigning values to the columns in the body of the `case` expression, and that's not the way to use a `case` expression. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're trying to do flow control inside an expression, and that's not the way to do it.

I think it can be better to do something like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `update_quantity`(IN iarticleid varchar(45), IN iquantity int(11))
BEGIN
    update product_varities
    set quantity = quantity - iquantity
    where article_id = iarticleid and quantity > 0;

    update product_varities
    set status = 0
    where article_id = iarticleid and quantity < 0;
END
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I can see what you mean. However with this the status is not set to 0 if the quantity is 0 or less

Comment: @Harry use `<=` instead of `<`

Comment: @Harry Happy to help (by the way, if you find this useful, upvote it and/or accept it ;) )

Answer (score 3):

You can write this as a single `update`, if you like:

```
UPDATE product_varities pv
    SET pv.quantity = (CASE WHEN pv.quantity > 0 THEN pv.quantity - iquantity
                            ELSE pv.quantity END),
        pv.status = (CASE WHEN pv.quantity < 0 THEN 0 ELSE pv.status)
    WHERE pv.article_id = iarticleid;
```

Comment: I have already accepted this answer, however this was exactly what I wanted to do initially +1